# Why the http request of my ionic application show Origin is http://localhost:8080?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httpclient

I am building a ionic application for android and ios device. The application uses httpClient module to communicate with a Node.js server. I run the app in my android smart phone by call:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

The app periodically send post request to the server. I check the request received in server side and find in the header show:

```
Origin: http://localhost:8080
```

Because the request is send from my smartphone, I thought it should be specific address. Can you explain why Origin has this address?

Comment: This is a page about CORS, but should help: https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors